How to change an inline keyboard markup view parameters in TDLib?
I need an opportunity of setting inline button color in my telegram client. Inline buttons are some options that bot can send with message to communicate with the user.
As I understand, it uses some default template that is not related to general list of colors and styles, which have declarated in Theme and ThemeColors classes of org.telegram.ui.ActionBar package.
So I really can't find out where is the class or method drawing these items. Maybe someone had any experience with similiar tasks in TDLib?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
